# Связь standalone приложения и приложения на GlassFish

Tags: java, websocket, glassfish

Есть обычное java application, работающее как процесс на моем домашнем сервере. Потребовалось соединить его через WebSocket с web интерфейсом. Для этого создал класс

```
    @ServerEndpoint("/serverendpointdemo")
public class WebSocketDemo  {
    @OnOpen
    public void handleOpen() {
        System.out.println("client is now connected....");
    }
    @OnClose
    public void handleClose() {
        System.out.println("client is now disconnected...");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String handleMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("recieve from client: " + message);
        String answerMessage = message;
        System.out.println("send to client: " + answerMessage);
        return answerMessage;
    }

    @OnError
    public void handleError(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Если деплоить приложение на GlassFish - ловит\отправляет тексты с web страницы. Вообщем WebSocketDemo работает. Но теперь ведь у меня нет точки входа `public static void main`. И мое приложение попросту не запускается. Я так понимаю надо чтобы  GlassFish как-то понял где точка входа в приложение. Пометить мои классы аннотациями?

1.Можно ли отдельно деплоить WebSocketDemo класс и отдельно запускать мое standalone приложение, а потом связывать их как-то?

2.Можно ли как-то открыть сокет из моего приложения, чтобы не деплоить все это на GlassFish?Ведь GlassFish мне нужен только для того, чтоб web страница могла обратиться к приложению по открытому им сокету.